# Swiper: How to remove blank spaces between each parallax transition

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I am a beginner in **Javascript** and while working on my portfolio website, I came across **Swiper Js**.

I have successfully been able to make a working slider of 4 slides **without parallax.** But, when I make use of parallax feature of swiper, I started to notice the **blank spaces appearing from the rightmost end**.

To quickly fix this, I did `slidesPerView: 1`. It resolved my problem. But, not satisfied with it ( for I wanted `slidesPerView: 1.2`).
So, is there any way in which `slidesPerView` **is preserved** and the **parallax causes no blank spaces?**

**NOTE**: **Any workaround using JS will also be accepted.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">

  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="slide-inner" style="background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-3.jpg)" data-swiper-parallax-x="90%"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="slide-inner" style="background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-2.jpg)" data-swiper-parallax-x="90%"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="slide-inner" style="background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-1.jpg)" data-swiper-parallax-x="90%"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="slide-inner" style="background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-4.jpg)" data-swiper-parallax-x="90%"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swiper-container {
  height: 900px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.swiper-slide-next{
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  
}

.swiper-slide{
  margin-left:0;
}

.slide-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 
}
```

**JS**

```
var options = {
  loop: true,
  speed: 1000,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  mousewheel: true,
  allowSlidePrev: false,
  slidesPerView:1.1,
  parallax: true,
  
};

var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", options);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/P0intMaN/a9gw350c/2/) regarding the same

**The carousel moves on mouse scroll**